# How to debug bundled JavaScript files of Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor

I'm doing changes in Experience Editor JavaScript command file of ribbon button, but I'm not able to find this file in browser (Chrome Dev Tools > Network > JS), so how I can find my file and how I can debug JavaScript files here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here that might help you:

1. You can set "WebEdit.EnableJSBundling" to "false", as a result, you will see much more JS files in Network -> JS, but it might affect page load in Experience Editor, so it is better to use on local or test environments
2. You can use [debbuger;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) instead of the breakpoint on your local environments